# ng-change within ng-repeat causing an angular error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-components

I have an angular component whose html partial is defined as follows:

```
<div    ng-class="{'chiptag2': !$ctrl.tag.isNew, 'chiptag-placeholder': $ctrl.tag.isNew, 'highlighted-tag': $ctrl.tag.isSelected}"
        ng-change="$ctrl.onChipChange($ctrl.tag)"
        ng-focus="$ctrl.onChipFocus($ctrl.tag)"
        ng-blur="$ctrl.onChipBlur($ctrl.tag)"
        contenteditable>
{{$ctrl.tag.title}}
</div>
```

The controller has the following snippets:

```
this.onChipFocus = function(tag){

    console.log('editableChipComponent onChipFocus for new tag');

};

this.onChipChange = function(tag){

    console.log('editableChipComponent onChipChange has '+tag.title);

};

this.onChipBlur = function(tag){

    console.log('editableChipComponent onChipBlur for '+tag.title);

};
```

The component is leveraged within an ng-repeat as follows:

```
<editable-chip-component
        ng-repeat="tag in tagcategory.tags"
        tag="tag"
        bluemoon="$ctrl.toggleTagSelection(tag)"
></editable-chip-component>
```

Everything works fine if I don't include the ng-change attribute in the component html partial.  But as soon as I add in the ng-change then the ng-repeat breaks after adding the first item, and the console shows the following error:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel&p1=ngChange
    at angular.js:38
    at V (angular.js:9722)
    at n (angular.js:9645)
    at g (angular.js:8881)
    at n (angular.js:9635)
    at angular.js:9980
    at angular.js:16648
    at m.$eval (angular.js:17972)
    at m.$digest (angular.js:17786)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:18080)
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?  I should be able to have an ng-change in an ng-repeat, right?

Thanks.

Comment: `ng-change` needs a binded variable (`ng-model`). You can't use it in a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `ng-change` on a div it is only applicable for input elements like `checkbox`, `radio`, `input box` etc.

It is asking for `ng-model`, i.e. to use `ng-change` you will have to use `ng-model` compulsorily.

In your case use `ng-click`.

Here is the [**Docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) for `ng-change`.

Comment: Thanks Saurabh, much appreciated

Comment: @Journeyman happy to know it worked for you. Please upvote it too :)